# Why are values not available in configuration phase?

Tags: angularjs

I was creating an application and needed to create a constant String. It was then that I realized that values and constant serve the common purpose. I do know about the fact that Constants are available during configuration phase.

But I wonder what stops values from doing the same, when they do not have dependencies too. Is there any other logic that differs among the both.

Since, Angular has kept both of them for so long, I think there must be any other reason. Someone following Angular from long time might help us understand the exact difference ??

Comment: ^becuase they can be decorated during config phase.

Answer (score 0):

From : https://gist.github.com/demisx/9605099

> A value is nothing more than a simple injectable value. The value can be a string, number but also a function. Value differs from constant in that value can not be injected into configurations, but it can be intercepted by decorators.

In decorator you can inject service, so it can only be done after configuration phase, this is why you can't inject value.